# Rails: Devise: User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Environment: Rails 3.2.3 with Devise

I would like to add a registration code to the registration form. The registration code is NOT in the users table. There's a separate registration_codes for that. The reason it's in the registration form, is that I would like to compare the code entered by the user filling out the registration form to what's in the registration codes table, and produce a value that will go into the users table.

I am getting an error message:

```
undefined method `registration_code' for #<User:0x007f91b57b7890>
```

and it's pointing to the code that displays the registration_code text box in views/registrations/new.html.erb

How do I get around the fact that registration_code is not part of the users table? The form was working fine, until I added the registration_code field to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a method in your User model that handles your registration code logic:

```
def registration_code=(code)
  # Check registation_codes table and produce a value that will go into the users table
end
```

Submitting a form with this new field should now call this method with the submitted value

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the crate method from executing?

Comment: It shouldn't.  It acts like the default setters that ActiveRecord generates based on your database fields, except that this one is specified explicitly.  This method is preferred, as it pushes the logic down to your model, and as a result makes it more easily testable and keeps your controller thin.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a form builder to create the form (a `form_for` block). In this case, you're probably using something like `<%= f.text_field :registration_code %>` to display the text field, but Rails can't find `registration_code` on the User model, because, like you said, it's not there.

Instead, try using `<%= text_field_tag :registration_code %>`. You can access this from your controller through `params[:registration_code]`

Comment: Yes, I am using form builder. Your suggestion should work. I was trying to use a hash like this: form_fields_hash.each do |label,value| <%= f.label :label %> <%= f.text_field :value %> end